# 1D Min-convolution in CUDA

Tags: arrays, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, cuda

I have two arrays, a and b, and I would like to compute the "min convolution" to produce result c.  Simple pseudo code looks like the following:

```
for i = 0 to size(a)+size(b)
    c[i] = inf
    for j = 0 to size(a)
        if (i - j >= 0) and (i - j < size(b))
            c[i] = min(c[i], a[j] + b[i-j])
```

(edit: changed loops to start at 0 instead of 1)

If the min were instead a sum, we could use a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), but in the min case, there is no such analog.  Instead, I'd like to make this simple algorithm as fast as possible by using a GPU (CUDA).  I'd be happy to find existing code that does this (or code that implements the sum case without FFTs, so that I could adapt it for my purposes), but my search so far hasn't turned up any good results.  My use case will involve a's and b's that are of size between 1,000 and 100,000.

Questions:

- Does code to do this efficiently already exist?
- If I am going to implement this myself, structurally, how should the CUDA kernel look so as to maximize efficiency?  I've tried a simple solution where each c[i] is computed by a separate thread, but this doesn't seem like the best way.  Any tips in terms of how to set up thread block structure and memory access patterns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative which might be useful for large `a` and `b` would be to use a *block* per output entry in `c`. Using a block allows for memory coalescing, which will be important in what is a memory bandwidth limited operation, and a fairly efficient shared memory reduction can be used to combine per thread partial results into a final per block result. Probably the best strategy is to launch as many blocks per MP as will run concurrently and have each block emit multiple output points. This eliminates some of the scheduling overheads associated with launching and retiring many blocks with relatively low total instruction counts.

An example of how this might be done:

```
#include <math.h>

template<int bsz>
__global__ __launch_bounds__(512)
void minconv(const float *a, int sizea, const float *b, int sizeb, float *c)
{
    __shared__ volatile float buff[bsz];
    for(int i = blockIdx.x; i<(sizea + sizeb); i+=(gridDim.x*blockDim.x)) {
        float cval = INFINITY;
        for(int j=threadIdx.x; j<sizea; j+= blockDim.x) {
            int t = i - j;
            if ((t>=0) && (t<sizeb))
                cval = min(cval, a[j] + b[t]);
        }
        buff[threadIdx.x] = cval; __syncthreads();
        if (bsz > 256) {
            if (threadIdx.x < 256) 
                buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+256]);
            __syncthreads();
        }
        if (bsz > 128) {
            if (threadIdx.x < 128) 
                buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+128]); 
            __syncthreads();
        }
        if (bsz > 64) {
            if (threadIdx.x < 64) 
                buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+64]);
            __syncthreads();
        }
        if (threadIdx.x < 32) {
            buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+32]);
            buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+16]);
            buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+8]);
            buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+4]);
            buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+2]);
            buff[threadIdx.x] = min(buff[threadIdx.x], buff[threadIdx.x+1]);
            if (threadIdx.x == 0) c[i] = buff[0];
        }
    }
}

// Instances for all valid block sizes.
template __global__ void minconv<64>(const float *, int, const float *, int, float *);
template __global__ void minconv<128>(const float *, int, const float *, int, float *);
template __global__ void minconv<256>(const float *, int, const float *, int, float *);
template __global__ void minconv<512>(const float *, int, const float *, int, float *);
```

[disclaimer: not tested or benchmarked, use at own risk]

This is single precision floating point, but the same idea should work for double precision floating point. For integer, you would need to replace the C99 `INFINITY` macro with something like `INT_MAX` or `LONG_MAX`, but the principle remains the same otherwise.

Comment: Thanks!  This is about 4x faster than my naive baseline on 1000x through of problems of size (1000,1000).  Baseline: 852.6 ms; This: 225.3 ms

Comment: @dan_x sorry for all the questions, what sort of GPU are you running on ?

Comment: @RobertCrovella happy to answer.  I have access to a few, but right now I'm primarily running on a Tesla C1060.

Answer (score 5):

**A faster version:**

```
__global__ void convAgB(double *a, double *b, double *c, int sa, int sb)
{
    int i = (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);
    int idT = threadIdx.x;
    int out,j;

    __shared__ double c_local [512];

    c_local[idT] = c[i];

    out = (i > sa) ? sa : i + 1;
    j   = (i > sb) ? i - sb + 1 : 1;

    for(; j < out; j++)
    {    
       if(c_local[idT] > a[j] + b[i-j])
          c_local[idT] = a[j] + b[i-j]; 
    }   

    c[i] = c_local[idT];
} 

**Benckmark:**
Size A Size B Size C Time (s)
1000   1000   2000   0.0008
10k    10k    20k    0.0051
100k   100k   200k   0.3436
1M     1M     1M     43,327
```

Old Version,
For sizes between 1000 and 100000, I tested with this naive version:

```
__global__ void convAgB(double *a, double *b, double *c, int sa, int sb)
{
    int size = sa+sb;

    int idT = (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x);
    int out,j;


    for(int i = idT; i < size; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        if(i > sa) out = sa;
        else out = i + 1;

        if(i > sb) j = i - sb + 1;
        else j = 1;


        for(; j < out; j++)
        {
                if(c[i] > a[j] + b[i-j])
                    c[i] = a[j] + b[i-j];
        }
    }
}
```

I populated the array `a` and `b` with some random double numbers and `c` with 999999 (just for testing). I validated the `c` array (in the CPU) using your function (without any modifications).

I also removed the conditionals from inside of the inner loop, so it will only test them once.

I am not 100% sure but I think the following modification makes sense. Since you had `i - j >= 0`, which is the same as `i >= j`, this means that as soon as `j > i` it will never enter this block 'X' (since j++):

```
if(c[i] > a[j] + b[i-j])
   c[i] = a[j] + b[i-j];
```

So I calculated on the variable `out` the loop conditional if `i > sa`, which means that the loop will finish when `j == sa`, if `i < sa` this means the loop will finish (earlier) on `i + 1` because of the condition `i >= j`.

The other condition `i - j < size(b)` means that you will start the execution of the block 'X' when `i > size(b) + 1` since `j` starts always = 1. So we can put `j` with the value that should begin, thus

```
if(i > sb) j = i - sb + 1;
else j = 1;
```

See if you can test this version with real arrays of data, and give me feedback. Also, any improvements are welcome.

**EDIT** : **A new optimization** can be implemented, but this one does not make much of a difference.

```
if(c[i] > a[j] + b[i-j])
    c[i] = a[j] + b[i-j];
```

we can eliminate the if, by:

```
double add;
...

 for(; j < out; j++)
 {
   add = a[j] + b[i-j];
   c[i] = (c[i] < add) * c[i] + (add <= c[i]) * add;
 }
```

Having:

```
if(a > b) c = b; 
else c = a;
```

it the same of having c = (a < b) * a + (b <= a) * b.

if a > b  then c = 0 * a + 1 * b; => c = b;
if a <= b then c = 1*a  + 0 *b;  => c = a;

```
**Benckmark:**
Size A Size B Size C Time (s)
1000   1000   2000   0.0013
10k    10k    20k    0.0051
100k   100k   200k   0.4436
1M     1M     1M     47,327
```

I am measuring the time of copying from CPU to GPU, running the kernel and copying from GPU to CPU.

```
GPU Specifications   
Device                       Tesla C2050
CUDA Capability Major/Minor  2.0
Global Memory                2687 MB
Cores                        448 CUDA Cores
Warp size                    32
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used you algorithm. I think it'll help you.

```
const int Length=1000;

__global__ void OneD(float *Ad,float *Bd,float *Cd){
    int i=blockIdx.x;
    int j=threadIdx.x;
    Cd[i]=99999.99;
    for(int k=0;k<Length/500;k++){
        while(((i-j)>=0)&&(i-j<Length)&&Cd[i+k*Length]>Ad[j+k*Length]+Bd[i-j]){
            Cd[i+k*Length]=Ad[j+k*Length]+Bd[i-j];
    }}}
```

I have taken `500` Threads *per* block. And, `500` blocks *per* Grid. As, the number of threads *per* block in my device is restricted to `512`, I used `500` threads. I have taken the size of all the arrays as `Length` (=1000).

**Working:**

1. `i` stores the Block Index and `j`  stores the Thread Index.
2. The  `for` loop is used as the number of threads are less than the size of the arrays.
3. The while loop is used for iterating `Cd[n]`.
4. I have not used Shared Memory because, I have taken lots of blocks and threads. So, the amount of Shared Memory required for each block is low.

**PS:** If your device supports more Threads and Blocks, replace `k<Length/500` with `k<Length/(supported number of threads)`